# How to integrate Webpack in a multi-page PHP application

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, webpack, gulp

I'm working on an old Codeigniter website where the Javascript codebase is messy and poorly structured and I would like to use Webback to manage the scripts. My goal would be start using it to bundle the code I have the way it is, and gradually refactoring it to make use of modules and imports.

At the moment I'm using Gulp on development (but mostly to minify the files) and [Carabiner](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Carabiner) (a Codeigniter library) to insert the scripts in the views.

The scripts, which are all written as IIFEs are not bundled, so in every controller function I have an array of the scripts needed in that page. For example:

```
public function homepage()
{
    $this->carabiner->js([
        ['libraryThatIOnlyNeedHere.min.js'],
        ['myscript1.js'],
        ['myscript2.js'],
        ['myscript3.js'],
    ]);
```

I would like to use Webpack to create a series of bundles so that I end up loading maximum two files on every page: one for the libraries and one for my scripts.

All the practical examples I've seen with Webpack, though, are for Single Page Applications where it's quite easy to bundle everything together.

What would be the best approach in my case? Considering that the code is still not ready to properly use modules and imports, shall I create many entry points in the Webpack configuration file, possibly one for every page and list every script needed in that page?

Comment: You'll need to create a different pair of bundles for each page which is going to be a real nightmare. As a first step you should instead make 2 bundles, 1 for common libraries and 1 for common scripts. Then each individual page can load additional scripts. Otherwise your only option is to have pairs of bundles for each route.

Comment: A real nightmare because I have to define lots of entry points? If that's the main issue, I wouldn't mind doing it. I guess it would be a matter of a couple of hours

Comment: Basically a solution would be creating something like "scripts.bundle.homepage.min.js" and "vendor.bundle.homepage.min.j" (names are hard) and this is for each page that needs JS. You can probably modify use gulp with webpack and make the bundles as part of your gulp process. Then you'd need to modify each controller route to serve the bundles instead of the raw script files.

Comment: but at some point I should modify the controllers anyway. I think the code in common each page is not that much, so I imagine it's better to have separate bundles

Comment: Also take a look at [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) it offers some nice features and you don't necessarily need laravel to make use of it

Answer (score 2):

Main idea behind webpack is to build modules graph from provided sources and then to combine it into bundles. If your code doesn't have explicit dependencies - it may be good idea to start with creating a module from every file using any of available approaches (AMD, CommonJS, etc). You will need to create module identifiers and define dependencies for every module. It may be worth to read [this article](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) for example.

As intermediate step you may want to use some loader like [Require.JS](http://www.requirejs.org/) to load your modularized code.

Until this step will be done - there is not much use of Webpack.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I don't know if it's worth using a new technology (AMD, common etc.) only to discard it afterward. Also, just to make sure I understand: if I create the modules with, let's say, CommonJS, I should still go in every controller and change the JS files I include. Would it be so bad to create explicit bundles with webpack and refactor the code afterward?

Comment: @Carlo webpack will look into entry point that you will give to it and will search for references to other modules into source. Legacy code obviously have no such references (since they're implicit) and hence your bundle will consist of single module - pretty useless. You need to provide webpack with a way to build a graph of modules, using any of available approaches (AMD, CommonJS, native JS modules or anything else, webpack have loader for). But the step of building explicit dependencies for every module is necessary. Webpack will convert your modules later by itself, so don't worry

Comment: thanks for your answer and info. I did more research with the info you provided and I've found this article (https://medium.com/eventmobi/how-to-incrementally-switch-to-webpack-203a1b431f7a) which describes an approach to switching to Webpack gradually that seems to fit perfectly my needs